# Stored procedure and trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I had a task -- to create update trigger, that works on real table data change (not just update with the same values). For that purpose I had created copy table then began to compare updated rows with the old copied ones. When trigger completes, it's neccessary to actualize the copy:

```
UPDATE CopyTable SET
    id = s.id,
    -- many, many fields
FROM MainTable s WHERE s.id IN (SELECT [id] FROM INSERTED)
                 AND CopyTable.id = s.id;
```

I don't like to have this ugly code in the trigger anymore, so I have extracted it to a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateCopy AS
BEGIN
UPDATE CopyTable SET
    id = s.id,
    -- many, many fields
    FROM MainTable s WHERE s.id IN (SELECT [id] FROM INSERTED)
    AND CopyTable.id = s.id;
END
```

The result is -- Invalid object name 'INSERTED'. How can I workaround this?

Regards,

Comment: Are you simply trying to call the stored procedure from within the trigger or are you likely to call the procedure other places as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real question is "How to pass array of GUIDs in a stored procedure?" or, more wide, "How to pass an array in a stored procedure?".

Here is the answers:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Answer (score 4):

Leave the code in the trigger. `INSERTED` is a pseudo-table only available in the trigger code. Do **not** try to pass around this pseudo-table values, it may contain a very large number of entries.

This is T-SQL, a declarative data access language. It is not your run-of-the-mill procedural programming language. Common wisdom like 'code reuse' does not apply in SQL and it will only cause you performance issues. Leave the code in the trigger, where it belongs. For ease of re-factoring, generate triggers through some code generation tool so you can easily refactor the triggers.

Comment: I agree with Remus.   My code will work, but it is a Work-around only.  If your only reason for having to do it is you don't like ugly code in the trigger, leave it alone.   If you have some other reason, the stuff I wrote will allow you to work around it....

Comment: OK. Actually, it's SQLCLR trigger and the reason to create the procedure was trying to improve perfomance, as I send the same gigantic text into SQL server each time per call.

Comment: why is your trigger a SQLCLR trigger? Perhaps you need to explain more about what you are trying to do. I would never consider using a CLR in a trigger as it is almost alawys slower for processing than regular SQL.

Comment: It contains a lot of bussiness logic, so I decided to write it in C#. And since the module has to be "invisible" for an upper-level application, it is whole implemented as a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that INSERTED is only available during the trigger

**-- Trigger changes to build list of id's**

```
DECLARE @idStack VARCHAR(max)
SET @idStack=','
SELECT @idStack=@idStack+ltrim(str(id))+',' FROM INSERTED
```

**-- Trigger changes to call stored proc**

```
EXEC updateCopy(@idStack)
```

-- **Procedure to take a comma separated list of id's**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateCopy(@IDLIST VARCHAR(max)) AS
BEGIN
UPDATE CopyTable SET
    id = s.id,
    -- many, many fields

    FROM MainTable s WHERE charindex(','+ltrim(str(s.id))+',',@idList) > 0
    AND CopyTable.id = s.id;
END
```

Performance will not be great, but it should allow you to do what you want.

Just typed in on the fly, but should run OK

Comment: Nice hack! Thank you. But as I tried to speed the trigger up, it's not an option. (Since the trigger is SQLCLR, the copying SQL script is being called via ADO.Net as a new query every time, I guess it's better to make a stored procedure to give the server chance to cache the script).